# !== Comparison Operator Should Be True but Isn't

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, comparison

```js
function nonUniqueElements(data) {
  var duplicates = [];
  var compArr = data;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < compArr.length; j++) {
      console.log('Comparing ' + data[i] + ' to ' + compArr[j]);
      if (data[i] === compArr[j]) {
        console.log('Found match first pass');
        console.log(data.indexOf(i), compArr.indexOf(j));
        if (data.indexOf(i) !== compArr.indexOf(j)) {
          console.log('Also passes second pass')
          console.log('Pushing ' + data[i] + ' to new array')
          duplicates.push(data[i]);
          console.log(duplicates);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log('End of run through');
  }

  return (duplicates);
}

console.log(nonUniqueElements([5, 5, 5, 5]));
```

I'm trying to return all non-unique values in an array. I've duplicated the array and am running a nested loop to compare the copy against the original.

When it finds a match (in this case every time), there's a second check to ensure that only values at a different index are pushed to a new array.

I've put some <kbd>console.log()</kbd>s to help me step through the program. Even when <kbd>console.log(data.indexOf(i), compArr.indexOf(j))</kbd> is printing different values, the block of code in the <kbd>if (data.indexOf(i) !== compArr.indexOf(j))</kbd> statement isn't running.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some sample Data would be useful.

Comment: Weird line there `if (data.indexOf(i) !== compArr.indexOf(j)) {`, shouldn't it be  something like `i !== j`

Comment: You are looking for index of `0, 1, 2, 3 ,4` not `5`... look: `console.log(i, data.indexOf(i), j, compArr.indexOf(j));`

Comment: You are looking at `compArr.indexOf(0)`, `compArr.indexOf(1)`, `compArr.indexOf(2)`, etc

Answer (score 1):

In JS, the indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string/array. You can tell it's wrong since in the console.log you always get the value -1.
What you need to compare is data[i] and compArr[j].

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use Array.reduce...

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,66,44,66]

var result = array.reduce((prev,value) => { 
                if ( prev.exists[value] ) { prev.dupes[value] = true; } 
                prev.exists[value] = true; 
                return prev; 
              },{ exists: {}, dupes: {} })
              
var duplicates = Object.keys(result.dupes);

console.log('duplicates',duplicates);

var filterDupes = array.filter(value => result.dupes[value])

console.log('fitlerDupes',filterDupes);

var mapDupes = array.map(value => result.dupes[value] ? value : null)

console.log('mapDupes',mapDupes);

for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++ ) {
  if ( !result.dupes[array[i]] ) { array.splice(i,1); i--; }
}

console.log('Original Array',array);
```

Comment: Thanks. The exercise wants every non-unique value returned, so the same array with just unique values removed. Would reduce not work in this instance?

Comment: It's returning a new Array, but you could filter the Array using results.dupes.

Or if the want the actual array then you'll need to splice out the values which are non-unique ( ie. result.dupes ).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data.indexOf(i) !== compArr.indexOf(j)) {
```

Why are you comparing indexes of i and j ?
i and j are indexes themselves, not elements.
Don't you mean

```
if (data[i] !== compArr[j]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare two `true` values.

Take a look at the definition of `indexOf` is:

- `Array.indexOf`: method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.
- `String.indexOf`: method returns the index within the calling `String` object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

So, in your condition `if (data.indexOf(i) !== compArr.indexOf(j))` you're comparing the index of `i` and `j` that holds the numbers of `0` to `3` (data.length). In your Array, all the values have been set to `5` witch is the reason that you get `-1` in return of `indexOf`, `[5,5,5,5].indexOf(0) === -1`.

If you're trying to compare the values in data Array you have to compare the values not index of values. Like this: `if (data[i] !== compArr[j])`.

At the end I recommend you to read this document [Truthy and Falsy: When All is Not Equal in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)